# Processing list object

Tags: r, list

I have a list object in R that contains further lists, of three vectors each. What is the quickest way to generate three matrices, the first of which has all of the first vectors as rows, the second has all of the second vectors as rows, and the third has all of the third? For example, given:

```
metalist <- list(list(c(1,1),c(11,11),c("a","a")),
                 list(c(2,2),c(22,22),c("b","b")),
                 list(c(3,3),c(33,33),c("c","c")))
```

I would like to get to three matrices (or data.frames), the first consisting of:

```
1 1

2 2

3 3
```

The second consisting of

```
11 11

22 22

33 33
```

And the third consisting of

```
a a

b b

c c
```

Given that in reality the metalist has 50,000 list objects, a for loop that extracts the vector elements and progressively assembles the matrices takes forever, so I would be looking for something quicker. I'm guessing there may be some clever use of `unlist()` but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I'm hoping you are not trying to create 50K matrices in your global environment? It will be better to keep those matrices within the list

Comment: David: No I am trying to create three matrices of 50,000 rows each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will create a list of three matrices:

```
my_outcome <- list()
for (i in 1:3)
{
    my_outcome[[i]] <- t(as.data.frame(lapply(metalist, `[[`, i)))
}
```

It does use a loop, but only over the number of matrices, so it should work in your case.

Comment: Wow, that's cool. So in lapply, you're applying the function `[[` to metalist. What is that function (just for my learning)?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Using `[` and `[[` in apply functions is often really useful.

Comment: Oh, never mind. It's just the extractor function. I didn't know it could be provided to lapply() in this way.

Comment: Yes that's right. Using the backticks lets R know you're using it as a function rather than how you normally index objects in R. This is available for R operators as well.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `do.call(Map,c(f=___,...))` is a useful one to have in your toolbox. Using `list` in the blank "transposes" the structure, using `rbind` will produce your desired matrices:

```
do.call(Map,c(f=rbind,metalist))

[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    3    3

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   11   11
[2,]   22   22
[3,]   33   33

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "a" 
[2,] "b"  "b" 
[3,] "c"  "c"
```

Comment: That's genius - I still can't figure out the logic of how it works, but it definitely does.

Comment: @thelatemail It expands to `Map(f=rbind,metalist[[1]],metalist[[2]],metalist[[3]])`, which is a list starting `rbind(metalist[[1]][[1]],metalist[[2]][[1]],metalist[[3]][[1]])`, continuing with 2 for the second indices, etc.

Comment: This is a lisp idiom, where it would be written `(apply map f ...)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - very clear. It is amazingly concise code for an otherwise potentially awkward solution.

Comment: Wow, that is cool. I need to play with this construct more. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to completely ignore for loops, the following also gets the job done:

```
lapply(1:3, function(y) {
do.call(rbind,lapply(metalist, function(x) x[[y]]))
})
```